# Get max + min in one line with linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How can I change this method so it also returns Max(t.StartTime) and Min(t.StartTime) with only using it in one line as below?

```
 public IQueryable<Timetable> GetTimetables()
    {
        return from t in _entities.Timetables
               select t;
    }
```

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head (read: untested) and presuming StartTime is non-nullable:

```
public class TimetableWithMaxMin
{
    public Timetable Timetable { get; set; }
    public DateTime Max { get; set; }
    public DateTime Min { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<TimetableWithMaxMin> GetTimetables()
{
    return from t in _entities.Timetables
           select new TimetableWithMaxMin
           {
               Timetable = t,
               Max = _entities.Timetables.Max(t => t.StartTime),
               Min = _entities.Timetables.Min(t => t.StartTime)
           };
}
```

This gets considerably more complicated when StartTime is nullable.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is applicable to Entity framework but with linq it's something like this

```
 public IQueryable<Timetable> GetTimetables()
    {
        return from t in _entities.Timetables
               select new {maxt = Max(t.StartTime), mint = Min(t.StartTime)};
    }
```

Comment: seems like there is some syntax issues

Comment: He forgot the `t =>`, as in `t => t.StartTime`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747.aspx#maxSimple

Comment: t = > is used for lambdas, that would something like this GetTimeTables().Select(t => new {maxt = Max(t.StartTime), mint = Min(t.StartTime)})

Comment: Max and Min both **require** an expression. See the link I posted, Omu.