# Get max & min from Entity Framework, in one query and with best query possible

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generated-sql

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707531/get-max-min-in-one-line-with-linq) question, but what I would like to do is obtain something close to this generated SQL:

```sql
select MAX(Column), MIN(Column) from Table WHERE Id = 1
```

When I try this:

```cs
var query = from d in db.Table
            where d.Id == 1
            select new
            {
                min = db.Table.Max(s => s.Column),
                max = db.Table.Min(s => s.Column)
            };
```

The generated sql looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [C2]
    FROM   [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        MAX([Extent2].[Column]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent2] ) AS [GroupBy1]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        MIN([Extent3].[Column]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent3] ) AS [GroupBy2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = 1) AND (1 IS NOT NULL)
```

I also tried this:

```cs
var query = from d in db.Table
           where d.Id == 1
           group d by d.Id into grp
           let min = grp.Min(s => s.Column)
           let max = grp.Max(s => s.Column)
           select new { min, max };
```

Which gives this:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project2].[C2] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        (SELECT 
            MAX([Extent2].[Column]) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[Id] = 1) AND (1 IS NOT NULL) AND ([Project1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id])) AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
            [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Id]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[Id] AS [K1], 
                MIN([Extent1].[Column]) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = 16) AND (16 IS NOT NULL)
                GROUP BY [Extent1].[Id]
            )  AS [GroupBy1]
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project2]
```

They both work, and the performance hit is probably negligible, so it's mostly aesthetic:
The two generated queries both hurt my eyes.

Comment: What if you write `group d by true into grp`?

Comment: @Magnus, little/no difference

Answer (score 14):

Try removing the `let` statements - the below produces expected results:

```
var q = from d in db.Table
        where d.Id == 1
        group d by d.Id into g
        select new
        {
            Id = g.Key, // shown for illustrative purposes
            ColumnMin = g.Min( gi => gi.Column ),
            ColumnMax = g.Max( gi => gi.Column )
        };

var result = q.SingleOrDefault();
```

Resulting SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Id],
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [K1], 
        MIN([Extent1].[Column]) AS [A1], 
        MAX([Extent1].[Column]) AS [A2]
        FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[Id]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Answer (score 12):

Here we are, 8 years later! But an answer nonetheless!

```
db.Table
  .Where(d => d.Id == 1)
  .GroupBy(_ => 1,
    (_, records) => new
                    {
                        Max = records.Max(r => r.Column),
                        Min = records.Min(r => r.Column)
                     });
```

This results in:

```
SELECT MAX([o].[Column]) AS [Max], MIN([o].[Column]) AS [Min]
FROM [Table] AS [o]
WHERE [o].[Id] = 1
GO
```

Note that in "Group by **1**" the 1 has nothing to do with the ID from the query!

Comment: Is it more efficient than supplying explicit grouping value, even if it really makes no sense here... ? Just looking more accurate :)

Comment: The question did not specify, although examples are indicating Sql-server, but I though worth mentioning that on Npgsql, this will generate a sub-query and group by, something like:

```
SELECT MAX(t.column), MIN(t.column)
  FROM (
   SELECT column, 1 AS "Key"
   FROM table -- and optional WHERE
  ) AS t
  GROUP BY t."Key"
```
But as far as I see, it does not affect execution plan (analyzed on v14).

Great suggestion BTW

Answer (score -4):

```
var query = from d in db.Table
            where d.Id == 1
            select
            {     
                d.Max(t =>t.yourColName),  
                d.Min(t =>t.yourColName)  
            };
```

Comment: In above code from your table first select the records with associated with d.Id==1 , after that select as per your requirement Max and Min Column

Comment: I'm not the OP, just giving advice on how you can improve your answer instead of just having code in the answer without an explanation (For the OP and future people looking for an answer)

Comment: Nice, except that it doesn't compile.